# dumpcap で特定のホストとポートを同時に除外することは可能ですか？

Tags: network, wireshark

Wiresharkの `dumpcap` を使用してキャプチャをとっていますが、以下のことを実現したく必要なオプションについて知見のある方がいらっしゃれば教えて下さい。

特定のホストに対する特定のポート通信のみを、キャプチャの除外にする。

`-f` の後で単純にホストのみを除外するなら、not hostアドレス　でできると思いますが、ポートをアンド条件にしたく。
イメージとしては、not (ホストアドレス　& 特定ポート) という形が可能なのかが知りたいです。

Comment: [wireshark-filter - The Wireshark Network Analyzer 3.4.3](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html#Logical%20expressions) の "Logical expressions" の項に、"Expressions can be grouped by parentheses as well." と書かれています。実際、`not (host [ip address] && tcp port [port number])` などとして capture してみると想定通りの結果になっている様です。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！頂いた内容で検証してみようと思います。